# Decryption bug using des ede, javax.crypto.badpaddingexception

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, padding, des

I've been stuck on a bug in my code, it will not let me decrypt properly!
I am only passing eight bytes of data to dataBytes and I am passing 
a 24 byte key to keyBytes.
I am trying to return the decrypted data as an array of bytes.
I keep getting the bad padding exception.

Thanks!

Here is the code snippet:

```
private static byte[] DESEdeDecrypt(byte[] keyBytes, byte[] dataBytes){

    byte[] decryptedData = null;
    try{
        DESedeKeySpec keySpec = new DESedeKeySpec(keyBytes, 0); 
        SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DESede");
        SecretKey key = keyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec); 
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        decryptedData = cipher.doFinal(dataBytes);
    }
    catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}  

    return decryptedData;
```

Comment: If you have not specified any padding on the other side, try and use "DESede/ECB/NoPadding"...

Answer (score 1):

You must use the same padding to decrypt as you did to encrypt.  It is better to set it explicitly rather than to rely on defaults.  Best also to specify the mode at both ends as well:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
```

DESede is slow and obsolescent.  You shouldn't use it except for compatibility with old code.  For new work it is better to use AES.